# I want to create a account on blockchain using web3swift in IOS app, but I am new on blockchain don't know how to do. Please can anyone help me out?

Tags: web3js, ether, myetherwallet, web3-providers, ios

I want to create an account on the blockchain using web3swift in the IOS app, but I am new on blockchain don't know how to do it. Please, can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

- **Create an account on blockchain using web3swift**

> > With Private Key
>
> ```
> let password = "web3swift" // We recommend here and everywhere to use the password set by the user.
> let keystore = try! EthereumKeystoreV3(password: password)!
> let name = "New Wallet"
> let keyData = try! JSONEncoder().encode(keystore.keystoreParams)
> let address = keystore.addresses!.first!.address
> let wallet = Wallet(address: address, data: keyData, name: name, isHD: false)
> ```

And

> > With Mnemonics Phrase
>
> ```
> let password = "web3swift"
> let bitsOfEntropy: Int = 128 // Entropy is a measure of password strength. Usually used 128 or 256 bits.
> let mnemonics = try! BIP39.generateMnemonics(bitsOfEntropy: bitsOfEntropy)!
> let keystore = try! BIP32Keystore(
>     mnemonics: mnemonics,
>     password: password,
>     mnemonicsPassword: "",
>     language: .english)!
> let name = "New HD Wallet"
> let keyData = try! JSONEncoder().encode(keystore.keystoreParams)
> let address = keystore.addresses!.first!.address
> let wallet = Wallet(address: address, data: keyData, name: name, isHD: true)
> ```

For more information on web3swift click [Here!](https://github.com/matter-labs/web3swift/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#create-account)